# Generating bone bind matrix with THREE.JS for OpenGL application

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.js exporter for Blender to export rigged model into my application. But there is no bone matrix in generated JSON data. As sample:

```
{
   "name": "W_Hips",
   "rotq": [-0.845519,0.00128,5.9e-05,0.533943],
   "scl": [1,0.990953,0.959433],
   "pos": [0.00022,5.09513,-0.466128],
   "parent": -1
}
```

How can I generate bind matrix for bone using this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything was too easy

```
glm::mat4 l_translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f),m_vPosition); // "pos" from JSON data
glm::mat4 l_rot = glm::mat4_cast(m_qRotation); // "rotq" from JSON data
glm::mat4 l_scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.f),m_vScale); // "scl" from JSON data
glm::mat4 l_local = l_translate*l_rot*l_scale;

if(m_parent == NULL) m_matrix = l_local;
else m_matrix = m_parent->m_matrix*l_local;
m_bindMatrix = glm::inverse(m_matrix);

for(size_t i=0; i < m_childBoneVector.size(); i++) m_childBoneVector[i]->generateBindPose(); // same calculation for children
```